# Pass data(String or int) to Content Provider in android.....SharedPreferences Tried but seems inaccessible here

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sharedpreferences

I was 'trying to use Shared Preferences in ContentProvider'..........It seems that it is not possible.......

But at the end I want to send an id (int or Sting) from My_Activity to Content Provider for that I was Using SharedP......Any other alternative

I am calling CP like this

```
   PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
   if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) 
   {
      Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);
      startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);
   } 
   else 
   {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `SharedPreferences` is to store configuration data, it's not a communication channel.

If the id you want to pass is related to the action that's to be performed you can append it as a query parameter to your `Uri` using [`Uri.Builder.appendQueryParameter(String, String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html#appendQueryParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Your code will look like this:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI
    .buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("id", "123456").build());
```

The resulting `Uri` will look like this:

```
content://YOUR.AUTHORITY/YOUR/PATH?id=123456
```

In your `ContentProvider` you can use [`Uri.getQueryParameter(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getQueryParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the parameter value.

Comment: thank you for answer....this one is best for Content Provider n will solve the problem(I tried it)......to keep it simple.....In my problem instead ContentProvider I used intents and my issue solved...Cannt upvote as repo is not 15 in Stackoverflow....:)